# Getting a formatting error on the output of any MySQL stored procedure I try

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am sure that I am missing some small but important detail, but need to help to see why I am consistantly getting an error when I add in the SELECT @output in my input like this. I have looked at many aritcles and answers but none of them are quite what I am looking at:

```
let connection = mysql.createConnection(config,{CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS: true});

(this line is the issue)
**let sql = 'CALL sp_whatever(?,@usernameOut);select @usernameOut;'**

await connection.query(sql, [param1],
        function(err,rows){
        console.log("INSIDE MySQL1");
```

I am doing this in Node JS and most examples are acutally in PHP. I have not found anything that is exactly what I am looking for (why am I getting a formatting error when I set it up like other examples or tutorials?)

I am using MySQL 5.7 on my Azure LInux server and the MySQL stored procedure looks like this: (in case the issue is inside the Stored Procedure itself)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`someDB`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetUsername`(
IN userIdVal INT,
OUT usernameOut NVARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT username INTO usernameOut
    FROM players
    WHERE userId = userIdVal AND avatarId = 0 AND Gender  IS NULL AND active = 1 ;
END
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
err.message: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select @username' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my real problem was a Node JS one. I was unable to get the output because it was a second command. I had read that I needed to add in multipleStatements: true if I wanted/needed to process multiple commands. What I didn't figure out until tonigt was that it had to be added to the config file to work correctly. Works great now!